# Regex, match between 2 words (inclusive) and include up to the next new line

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to replace on the following data, from `Item Id:` to the end of the last line that contains `end:`

```
Some junk
Item Id: 401421502995 
end: blah blah blag, Item Id: 401343012211
end: blah blah blah blah basdfasd
Some other junk
```

So in essence all this stuff will be replaced

```
Item Id: 401421502995 
end: blah blah blag, Item Id: 401343012211
end: blah blah blah blah basdfasd
```

Leaving me with

```
Some junk
Some other junk
```

This comes in several configurations, however the line `end:` is on needs to go

Here's what i have, it matches up to the `end:` but doesn't continue to the end of the line

`(Item Id:).*?(end:)`

How do i do include `\n` my brain is shot

Comment: Try [`(?m)^Item Id:(?s:.*?)end:.*\n?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's the ticket

Comment: Wait, I am not sure, maybe [`Item Id:(?s:.*?)end:(?:(?!Item Id:).)*\n?`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Item+Id%3a%28%3fs%3a.*%3f%29end%3a%28%3f%3a%28%3f!Item+Id%3a%29.%29*%5cn%3f&i=Some+junk%0d%0aItem+Id%3a+401421502995+%0d%0aend%3a+blah+blah+blag%2c+Item+Id%3a+401343012211%0d%0aend%3a+blah+blah+blah+blah+basdfasd%0d%0aSome+other+junk&r=)? I see `Item Id` can start at any location, even on the `end:` line.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yep that last one seems to work, answer it up and get the gravey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
Item Id:(?s:.*?)end:(?:(?!Item Id:).)*\n?
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Item%20Id%3A%28%3Fs%3A.%2A%3F%29end%3A%28%3F%3A%28%3F!Item%20Id%3A%29.%29%2A%5Cn%3F&i=Some%20junk%0D%0AItem%20Id%3A%20401421502995%20%0D%0Aend%3A%20blah%20blah%20blag%2C%20Item%20Id%3A%20401343012211%0D%0Aend%3A%20blah%20blah%20blah%20blah%20basdfasd%0D%0ASome%20other%20junk&r=).

**Details**

- `Item Id:` - a literal substring
- `(?s:.*?)` - a modifier group with the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option enabled
- `end:` - a literal substring
- `(?:(?!Item Id:).)*` - 0+ occurrences of any char but LF that does not start an `Item Id:` char sequence (see [more details on this construct here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat))
- `\n?` - an optional LF char (it is optional to also match the last line in the input).

Comment: Awesome and thanks, its like 5:20 pm here, and my brain is already at home

Comment: It is 9:21 AM here :) and my brain is slowly turning on :)

Comment: BTW, a synonymous expression is [`Item Id:(?s:.*?)end:.*?(?:(?=Item Id:)|\r\n?|$)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Item+Id%3a%28%3fs%3a.*%3f%29end%3a.*%3f%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3dItem+Id%3a%29%7c%5cr%5cn%3f%7c%24%29&i=Some+junk%0d%0aItem+Id%3a+401421502995+%0d%0aend%3a+blah+blah+blag%2c+Item+Id%3a+401343012211%0d%0aend%3a+blah+blah+blah+blah+basdfasd%0d%0aSome+other+junk&r=).